# Cannot install pidgin

Tags: software-installation, software-center, package-management, pidgin

I am trying to install pidgin-ppa from software centre but it's showing The installation or removal of a software package failed

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package pidgin.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 174491 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pidgin_1%3a2.10.9-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pidgin (1:2.10.9-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pidgin-libnotify.
Preparing to unpack .../pidgin-libnotify_0.14-9ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pidgin-libnotify (0.14-9ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.6-1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...

(gconftool-2:10421): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140408-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Setting up pidgin (1:2.10.9-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up pidgin-libnotify (0.14-9ubuntu2) ...
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run `locale` and check output (in my case):

```
LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="it_IT.UTF-8"
...
```

then, generate locale and finally reconfigure (replace it_IT.UTF-8 with your lang):

```
sudo locale-gen it_IT.UTF-8

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

this should solve the problem